# Image name is not found

Tags: image, .htaccess, replace, http-status-code-404

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule .* /not/found/image [L]
```

This is the code I am using to replace any image that isn't found, but let's say I only wanted to replace the image that is called `image01.jpg` and it is not found. How do I only replace that image name?

Thanks in advance frank :)

Comment: frankmeacey, please, consider accept this answer if it fited your needs (click in the green V under the votes number). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} image01\.jpg$ 
RewriteRule .* /not/found/image [L]
```